# android:layout_gravity doesn't always work as expected

Tags: android

this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:textColor="#0000ff" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The textView is horizontally centered but why isn't the ProgressBar vertically centered?

ps. I know I can do this using relative layout. But I do not understand why it doesn't work using Linear?
ps2. why the down vote, it's a perfectly legit question?

Comment: because it has `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` try giving it a different value

Comment: @Thepoosh it has WIDTH set as fill_parent but not HEIGHT which is what matters here.

Comment: @gtumca-MAC that really does not give me the answer. I know I can get this working with relative but I am more interested why it doesn't work with Linear.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Try the one above

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:textColor="#0000ff" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wanna do it with linear layout

Answer (score 0):

First off I realize this is a very old question but maybe someone looking in to this might find this helpful.

I'm not completely sure why your exact example doesn't work, if you do by now be sure to let me know. I do know it works if you add an extra LinearLayout for your progressbar.
Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="#0000ff" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```